# How to auto-resize images of various kinds using PHP?

Tags: php, image, resize

Users on my site upload images of various dimensions.  Some might be huge some might be small so resizing to a default image might work but small images being resized would look ugly.  Is there anything i can do to resize all images to one size and make the quality clear without making it look crappy?

Comment: How is resizing everything to one size *not* resizing to a default size?

Comment: Which do you want? Standardization on a single size or multiple sizes? What is "HD"? What will you do to fill in "unused space" when images aren't in the same aspect ratio as The One True Output Image? I think you'll have to spend a lot more time thinking about what specifically you want your code to do...

Comment: About your small images, no, there is nothing you can do that will make them look good enlarged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to make small images "High Definition". No image can be scaled to a larger size without loosing clarity (with the exception of vector graphics, but I'm guessing that isn't what you're working with). You can, however, resize larger graphics into smaller ones.

Try [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) for an excellent image manipulation library, or see JohnPS's answer for a good solution for re-sizing larger images.

Comment: How do facebook, twitter, tumblr, pinterest do it?

Comment: More than likely there is a non-PHP (if I'd have to guess) script which performs various resizes and saves it on the server. I would guess that this operation would be handled by languages which are more suited for image processing, such as C/C++, Java, etc...

Comment: For this case, your best bet is to stick with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP PEAR package [Image_Transform](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Transform) that you can install to do basic resizing of images.

This package includes a function `fit` that will shrink an image to fit inside a box (width and height), but leave it the same size if it's already small enough. See [scaling function docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-transform.scaling.php).